# Uniqueness Principle for function types

Tags: type-theory, homotopy-type-theory

I am currently trying to understand the first chapter of the HoTT book and for 1.2 Functions Types of the book,

> Since it is by definition ``the function that applies $f$ to its argument'' we consider it to be definitional equal to $f$:
>   $$
> f\equiv (\lambda x.f(x))
> $$
>   This equality is the **uniqueness principle for functions types**, because it shows that $f$ is uniquely determined by its values.

I can understand its definitional equality as it is by construction. But I do not understand why we need to establish or state this uniqueness principle. I am tempted to think of this uniqueness principle as obvious, but I think there is some underlying reason for this. I am guessing it has to do with the big picture of how each type is introduced systematically by the formation, introduction, elimination, computation rules but I can't seem to relate to them.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not true "by construction".  Remember that at this point in the theory a "function" is an abstract undefined thing, not something "defined by its action on inputs" as it is in set theory.  The only thing we can do with a "function" is apply it to an argument; the only way we have to make "functions" is to $\lambda$-abstract take an expression involving a variable.  So if I have a "function" $f$, apply it to a variable $x$ to get an expression $f(x)$, then abstract that to get $\lambda x.f(x)$, I have a new "function".  There's nothing in this abstract picture (before we assert the uniqueness principle) that says that this new "function" must be the same as the "function" $f$ that I started with.

Comment: This question shows a common problem that many students have with definitions in math.  It comes up when you define a word that already has connotations, in this case "function".  The only data you can use in proofs based on this new definition are the properties given by the definition (until someone has proved some theorems you can use).  If the fact that a function in the general usage of mathematical English is determined by its values is not given in the definition, you can't use it.  In general, if you see a math definition of a word, throw away its connotations!

Comment: With your explanations, I think it also explains to me why in the first paragraph of 1.2 it says that functions are a primitive concept in type theory! Hence, in 1.5 Product types which is also a primitive concept, there is a need to prove that every element of $A \times B$ is a pair $(a,b)$. Then, the introduction of product types seems to be saying, ''I do not know product types are actually pairs, but by defining dependent functions out of product types, I can then prove that the elements of $A \times B$ are indeed the pairs I hoped for it to be.' Is this what it says?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: @Zhangsheng ''I do not know product types are actually pairs" But isn't that obvious from the fact that the constructor of product type creates elements by making pairs? Why bother proving that by defining dependent functions out of product types?

Comment: @pxc3110 The constructor tells you that *some* elements of product types are pairs, but by itself that doesn't tell you that *all* elements of product types are pairs.  You need some way to say "all elements of the type are obtained from its constructors", and for product types defined as in the HoTT Book, that's exactly what the elimination rule does.  (There is another way to define product types, called a "negative" presentation, where instead of an elimination rule you have primitive projections and a uniqueness principle $p \equiv (\pi_1(p),\pi_2(p))$, which then plays that role.)

Comment: @MikeShulman So the constructor has to be a bijection and hence its domain and codomain should have the same cardinality? And whenever a type constructor is defined you assume that it's well defined and you also have to verify that the constructor and eliminator are inverses to each other?

Comment: @pxc3110 Not all constructors are bijections.  For instance, a coproduct type $A+B$ has two different constructors $\mathsf{inl}:A\to A+B$ and $\mathsf{inr}:B\to A+B$, neither of which is a bijection.  And even in the case of product types where "morally" the single constructor is a bijection, you can't say that inside the theory nontrivially because there's no single type to be its "domain" until you've introduced the product type!  We can formulate the "pairing" constructor in curried form as $A\to (B\to (A\times B))$, but there's no way to say that that's a bijection.

Comment: In the case of function types, there isn't even a way to give the "$\lambda$-abstraction" constructor a nontrivial type inside the theory, since what it takes as input is "an expression with a free variable".  I'm not sure what you mean by "assume it's well defined" -- what would it mean for it to be ill-defined?  We do generally want the constructors and eliminators (potentially plural on both sides) to be "inverses" in some sense -- this is sometimes called "harmony" in type-theoretic parlance -- but the sense in which this is true is kind of metatheoretic and subtle.

Comment: @MikeShulman f:A->B is well defined if for each a in A, there exists a unique b in B such that f a = b. In other words, f has to be total and assigns a value that must be inside its codomain to each element in its domain.

Comment: What you said about bijections is true, but what I mean is that the disjoint union of all domains of all constructors you have has the same cardinality as their codomain. the combination of inr and inl defined as f x = if x in A, return inl x; else return inr x should be bijective.

Comment: @MikeShulman When I talked about assuming the constructor to be "well defined", I was quoting chapter 1.5: "By contrast, type theory reverses the situation: we
assume that a function on A × B is well-deﬁned as soon as we specify its
values on pairs, and from this (or more precisely, from its more general
version for dependent functions, below) we will be able to prove that every element of A × B is a pair."

Comment: @MikeShulman If you accept that constructors and eliminators have to inverses in some sense, then you also must accept that they have to be bijective in some sense, hence the domains and codomains have the same total cardinality.

Comment: @pxc3110 "assume that a function is well-defined" in that quote is just an informal manner of speaking; what it really means is that we give a rule allowing us to define a function on A x B by specifying its values on pairs (i.e. we give the elimination rule).  Formally, there is no separate "assumption" of "well-definedness", there is only the rule.  (Perhaps that wording is confusing.)

Comment: It's true that for (non-higher) inductive types the constructors are "collectively bijective" (although in homotopy type theory, where not all types are sets, it gets iffy to express this in terms of "cardinality").  I'm just saying there is no nontrivial way to say that inside the theory, because there's nothing to stand in for the domain of such a bijection that isn't tautologically identical to the codomain.

Comment: @MikeShulman But an elimination rule is presented as a function named "recursor" right after that passage. The way I interpret "assume that a function is well-defined", is that we assume well definedness of projections pr1 and pr2, which implies that our type constructor is one to one and they are left inverses for constructor by definition. Then show that projections are right inverses, which will imply that the constructor is onto as well hence bijective and its inverses are the projection functions.

Comment: @pxc3110 Yes, the eliminator (at least for inductive types) is a function.  I'm not sure what point you're making.  I already told you how to interpret "assume that a function is well-defined".

Comment: @MikeShulman Sorry for confusing you. What I was asking is about your saying "Formally, there is no separate "assumption" of "well-definedness", there is only the rule." But to me it seems that these two things are equivalent: well-definedness of projections and the beta rule(computation rule) which we're supposed to verify. This is because (a',b')=(a,b) => pr1(a,b)=pr1(a',b') iff (a',b')=(a,b) => a=a' for any a, a':A, b, b':B. rhs implies 1-1 ness of constructor, ie the beta rule. While it is true that there are only rules, their interactions have to obey beta and eta rules.

Comment: @pxc3110 I'm not sure whether "=" refers to judgmental or propositional equality, but in either case the fact that projections preserve equality doesn't involve beta-rules.  The fact that all operations of type theory preserve judgmental equality is separate primitive rules from the beta-rules, while the fact that they preserve propositional equality follows from the elimination rule for the latter (i.e. path induction).  Conversely, the beta-rules don't imply either of these facts in general, as you need to know that m=n implies pr1(m)=pr1(n) even when m and n are not syntactically pairs.